# Could it be possible to start multiple training at the same time?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I just started coding DNN and I was wondering if it could be possible to launch multiple training at the same time? Like with different parameters. Or will it slow down a lot the training?

Here for the context: I use a Ganomaly architecture in order to found anomalies in pictures and I have to change and try a few different combinations. I use Anaconda and during training, it shows that ~20% of memory is being used. My setup: Nvidia Quadro M6000, Cuda 9.0, cudNN 7.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could it be possible to start multiple training at the same time?

Yes, it is possible to start multiple instances but surely have an impact on your training speed.

One possible solution is to integrate [`GridSearchCV`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) in sklearn and Keras model. To this end, Keras also provide a wrapper, called [`keras.wrappers.scikit_learn`](https://keras.io/scikit-learn-api/) which you can set the number of jobs, in the `GridSearchCV`, to -1 in order to run them in parallel. See [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/grid-search-hyperparameters-deep-learning-models-python-keras/) for more details.

Here is a list of the hyper-parameter optimization solution.

- [HyperKeras](https://github.com/maxpumperla/hyperas)
- [Kopt](https://github.com/Avsecz/kopt)
- [Talos](https://github.com/autonomio/talos)

See [here](https://medium.com/@mikkokotila/a-comprehensive-list-of-hyperparameter-optimization-tuning-solutions-88e067f19d9) for more details.

Another possible option is Google-hyper-tuning, which of course needs to run on the cloud. See [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/using-hyperparameter-tuning) for more details.